# Using Custom Token for Login as User on Firebase Error

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, jwt

I got problems about the signInWithCustomToken method to logged in by token.

Here is my codebase:

```js
generateFirebaseSignInToken()
    .then((data) => {
      const customToken = data.data.generateFirebaseSingInToken;
      const auth = getAuth();
      signInWithCustomToken(auth,customToken)
          .then((userCredential) => {
            const user = userCredential.user;
            console.log("User successfully signed in:", user);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error("Error signing in:", error);
          });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error generating token:", error);
    });
```

Here is payload to while sending request to try login:

```js
{
    "token": "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6IjYzODBlZjEyZjk1ZjkxNmNhZDdhNGNlMzg4ZDJjMmMzYzIzMDJmZGUiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL3NlY3VyZXRva2VuLmdvb2dsZS5jb20vYXJjZWxpay1zdGF.........",
    "returnSecureToken": true
}
```

I got this error on console:

> Error signing in: FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-custom-token).

I check all the documentations for custom token and also when i tried to decode token its returning right project id and other etc information